# Can't install Meteorite package

Tags: package, meteor, router

I've installed Meteorite from NPM with

```
npm install -g meteorite
```

Now when I run

```
mrt add router

Installing Meteor

  branch: https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git#master

Installing smart packages


node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/myusername/.meteorite/meteors/meteor/meteor/4d98d8cb4e5a95e9e98953f44c872c9332a042a3'
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:373:18)
    at Object.mkdirSyncRecursive (/usr/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/wrench/lib/wrench.js:361:12)
    at [object Object]._load (/usr/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:125:12)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:73:18
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:89:5
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:216:5
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:281:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:70:17)
    at maybeExit (child_process.js:361:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:458:7)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation instruction at https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite#installing-meteorite mentions that `sudo -H npm install -g meteorite` is the correct installation command.

Probably, now you've got some root-owned folders in your directory structure (check out `~.npm/`), and `mrt` or Meteor hasn't sufficient privileges for installing packages.

For explanation and repairing your situation, see the instructions at https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite#permission-woes. It helped me.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this issue has been [reported before](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/issues/67). Inside that thread, [this workaround](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/issues/67#issuecomment-11067125) has apparently been successful.